# Reaction of grignard in presence of Halogen

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds, grignard-reagent

What happens when a Ketone  say $$RCOCH3$$  on reaction with grignard reagant in presence of X2 (halogen) what happens?? Can someone please explain

Comment: In the presence of X2? The Grignard will react with the elemental halogen first.

Answer (score 2):

Grignard reacts with the elemental halogen. Ketone will be left un-reacted with. If you have insufficient halogen in reactant side then the leftover  Grignard will react with the ketone to for the tertiary alcohol to quench all the reactants.
However I am enlisting the products Chlorination of Grignard reagents, RMgX, (where X = Br, I) gives considerable quantities of RI and RBr together with RCl. Bromination of RMgI results in RI and RBr. Bromination of RMgCl leads to RBr, and iodination of RMgX (where X =Cl, Br), to RI.